# Doubting whether I swallowed water or not

Tags: sawm, ramadan, wudu

Asalamualaykum,

If you’re making wudu and you’re up to the putting water in your mouth and you spat the water out then swallowed (whether it’s saliva or you just felt like you needed to swallow even if it’s nothing) but you’re not 100% sure if you swallowed the water or it could’ve just been your saliva does that invalid your fast? And what if after you spat out the water then swallowed your saliva and you’re doubting if you swallowed water or not, does that also invalid your fast?

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve felt like you’ve spat all the water out then it’s best to go with that rather than going with doubt, if you feel you’ve spat it out then go with that assumption.

Comment: I did spit the water out but what if you’re doubting whether you swallowed some water like left over water or drops that’s in your mouth after you spit the water out?

Comment: I normally spit out a bit after 2/3 times, after that go with what seems right for you but don’t make it excessive, last thing you want is to have a form of waswas during ramadan, Insha’allah go with what you feel right, or spit until your mouth feels dry